# Can't Convert XML into an input string in a C# SOAP Webservice Method

Tags: c#, json, xml, soap

I had the task to code a C# SOAP Webservice that Converts Data from JSON to the XML format and back. I already implemented the Service and the 2 Methods. The Convert Method from JSON to XML already works.
However I face Problems with the conversion from XML to JSON. I cant parse the input XML into the string the method wants. Because of Attributes in the XML, the XML cant be interpreted. Can somebody help?

This is my XML to JSON Method

```
public string ConvertXMLToJSON(string InputXMLData) {
    try {
      //Interprets the Input String into a XML File    
      var InterpretedXML = XDocument.Parse(InputXMLData);

     //Converts the Interpreted XML using the JSON Convert Funktion 
      string OutputJSONData = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(InterpretedXML);

      return OutputJSONData;

       //Filter out any Exception   
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      return $"Error while converting XML to JSON: {ex.Message}";
    }
  }
```

Also here is my SOAP Request with an example

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:ConvertXMLToJSON>
            <tem:InputXMLData>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
            </tem:InputXMLData>
        </tem:ConvertXMLToJSON>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I did already try to redefine the method using dynamic Variables which didnt work. Also I tried to define the InputString of the Method as an Literal String which also didnt work.

Comment: Your XML is invalid. Unless remove `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` then it is fine.

Comment: I already tried that but it only shows this error. <faultstring>End element 'InputXMLData' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found element 'note' from namespace ''.</faultstring> . Apperently It cant resolve the XML as a String and it gets even more difficult if i added attributes

Comment: Don't you need to escape the contents of the `<tem:InputXMLData>` tag so that any special character is converted to its equivalent escape sequence? e.g.: "<" escaped to ";lt;", ">" to "gt;", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your service expects the InputXMLData as a string. So you either need to pass a CDATA or escape the input data.

CDATA:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:ConvertXMLToJSON>
            <tem:InputXMLData>
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>]]>
            </tem:InputXMLData>
        </tem:ConvertXMLToJSON>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Escape:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:ConvertXMLToJSON>
            <tem:InputXMLData>
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;note&gt;&lt;to&gt;Tove&lt;/to&gt;&lt;from&gt;Jani&lt;/from&gt;&lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt;&lt;body&gt;Don&apos;t forget me this weekend!&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/note&gt;
            </tem:InputXMLData>
        </tem:ConvertXMLToJSON>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```